# Is there a more line efficient way of clearing textboxes in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for an effective way of clearing textboxes, ideally in a function.

I have tried using:

```
 {
     Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

     func = (controls) =>
         {
             foreach (Control control in controls)
                 if (control is TextBox)
                     (control as TextBox).Clear();
                 else
                     func(control.Controls);
         };

     func(Controls);
 }
```

The problem with the above solution is that I could not choose which text boxes were to be deleted.

`TextBoxName.Text = "";`
The above works however the only problem is that it takes up 200 lines
I have 61 boxes, i need a clear all button, that only clears 60 boxes (all except one)

i need clear row buttons, since the boxes are arranged in rows

there are 15 clear row buttons, each with 4 boxes, is there a for loop i can use that will only clear the ones i need (by name if possible)?

Comment: Store all your textboxes in your own `List<TextBox>` or even `List<List<TextBox>>`, seeing how they are arranged in rows.

Comment: Or *mark* (set the Tag) just those that don't need clearing (since it's just one, apparently, it's a quick edit). You probably need a recursive methods, though. It appears the TextBoxes are child of different containers.

Comment: @MartinNajemi, I am curious to know how the answer I had made on Feb1 and the answer which was posted and accepted today (after unmarking my answer) is different ?

Comment: @AnuViswan I was just wondering the same thing. If your answer was also "unmarked", then something smells fishy to me. I would flag either the question or the duplicate answer for moderator intervention if I were you. The two accounts have some similarities too. I don't want to jump to conclusions too fast but this might be a sock puppet kind of thing.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes, it was unmarked and given negative vote. That's what made me look into it, and i felt the accepted answer, which was answered minutes back was duplicate

Comment: @AnuViswan It's indeed an exact duplicate (except for the name of one variable). I already flagged the answer so moderators can look into this.

Comment: This does look suspicious, and the correct thing to do is to flag the moderators and let them take corrective action.

Comment: @AnuViswan: karma

Answer (score 1):

You could create a collection of TextBoxes to exempted and filter based on it. For example,

```
var exceptionList = new[] { textBox1 };
foreach(var textBox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x=> !exceptionList.Contains(x)))
{
   textBox.Clear();
}
```

If you want to filter based on the Control Name, you would use

```
foreach(var textBox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x=> !exceptionList.Contains(x.Name)))
{
   textBox.Clear();
}
```

Where `exceptionList` is collection of names of TextBoxes that needs to be exempted.